# SQL JOIN WITH GROUPBY AND WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
SELECT c.REGION,COUNT(*)COUNT 
FROM OAS_CONTRACT a
   INNER JOIN OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES b ON a.CONTRACT_ID=b.CONTRACT_ID
   INNER JOIN OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES_DETAIL c ON b.T2_CODE = c.T2_CODE
WHERE (a.EXPIRY_DATE >= SYSDATE)
GROUP BY c.REGION ORDER BY c.REGION
```

In above Oracle query WHERE clause has no effect. It is also returning contracts where `EXPIRY_DATE < SYSDATE` (Expired Contracts). I don't know how should I arrange above query.Please help me I am stuck!

```
OAS_CONTRACT

CONTRACT_ID EXPIRY_DATE
541         11/14/2017
561         11/14/2014
```

Query returns both It should only return 541 because its the non-expired.

The below query returns non-expire contracts

```
SELECT * FROM OAS_CONTRACT a WHERE (a.EXPIRY_DATE >= SYSDATE)
```

and this query returns expired contracts

```
SELECT * FROM OAS_CONTRACT a WHERE (a.EXPIRY_DATE < SYSDATE)
```

But when I Inner Join tables I am not getting the desired result.The below query returns both expired and non-expired contracts.

```
SELECT c.REGION,COUNT(*)COUNT 
    FROM OAS_CONTRACT a
       INNER JOIN OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES b ON a.CONTRACT_ID=b.CONTRACT_ID
       INNER JOIN OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES_DETAIL c ON b.T2_CODE = c.T2_CODE
    WHERE (a.EXPIRY_DATE >= SYSDATE)
    GROUP BY c.REGION ORDER BY c.REGION
```

---

I am adding more detail here to clarify the issue I am facing.

I have following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE OAS_CONTRACT
(
  CONTRACT_ID             NUMBER                NOT NULL,
  CATEGORY                VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  EXPIRY_DATE          DATE)

CREATE TABLE OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES 
(
 CONTRACT_ID               NUMBER NOT NULL,
 T2_CODE                   VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
 )

CREATE TABLE OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES_DETAIL 
(
  T2_CODE                  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
 REGION                    VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
 )

--NON-EXPIRED
INSERT INTO OAS_CONTRACT VALUES (10,'Test',SYSDATE+60);
--EXPIRED
INSERT INTO OAS_CONTRACT VALUES (11,'Test2',SYSDATE-60);

INSERT INTO OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES (10,'ABC123');
INSERT INTO OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES (11,'ABC124');

INSERT INTO OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES_DETAIL ('ABC123','HQ-1');
INSERT INTO OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES_DETAIL ('ABC124','HQ-2');
```

I need count of non-expired contracts grouped by region

```
REGION         COUNT
HQ-1           1
```

but I am getting this

```
REGION         COUNT
HQ-1           1
HQ-2           1
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Or you not getting desired result? What's your question?

Comment: No I am not getting any Error. The Query returns all Contracts even if the EXPIRY_DATE < SYSDATE. WHERE CONDITION is not working.

Comment: So do you need expired or non expired rows? I dont see issues with above query if you need non expired contract. Can you paste your data.

Comment: I need non-expired contracts

Comment: Paste your schema and rows in those schema and which row is troublesome

Comment: CONTRACT_ID EXPIRY_DATE
541         11/14/2017
561         11/14/2014

Query returns both It should only return 541 because its the non-expired.

Comment: If you are using Oracle, then why did you also add the `mysql` and `sql-server` tags?

Comment: What is the data type of `EXPIRY_DATE` ?

Comment: EXPIRY_DATE has DATE datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want the `min()` of `EXPIRY_DATE` to be later than the sysdate:

```
SELECT c.REGION, COUNT(*) as COUNT 
FROM OAS_CONTRACT a INNER JOIN
     OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES b
     ON a.CONTRACT_ID = b.CONTRACT_ID INNER JOIN
     OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES_DETAIL c
     ON b.T2_CODE = c.T2_CODE
GROUP BY c.REGION
HAVING MIN(a.EXPIRY_DATE) >= SYSDATE
ORDER BY c.REGION;
```

As a hint:  using table aliases is a good thing.  Making them abbreviations for the table names makes the query much easier to understand.  I would suggest using `c`, `co`, and `od` instead of `a`, `b`, and `c`.

EDIT:

`EXPIRY_DATE` is not being printed in the standard form for an Oracle date.  I suspect it is being stored as a string -- bad, bad, bad.  If so, then this might be the fix you need:

```
WHERE to_date(a.EXPIRY_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') >= SYSDATE
```

EDIT II:

In your sample data, it would seem that `EXPIRY_DATE` might be `NULL`.  If so, then try this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE a.EXPIRY_DATE >= SYSDATE or a.EXPIRY_DATE IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon but it is producing same result. I have three tables OAS_CONTRACT It contains the contract detail like CONTRACT_ID,EXPIRY_DATE of Contract. Other Table is OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES it contains T2_CODE and CONTRACT_ID.Third Table OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES_DETAIL contains T2_CODE,REGION. Now I need to count and Group Non-Expired Contracts by REGION i-e EXPIRY_DATE>SYSDATE but it is returning expire and non-expired both.

Comment: Query is 100% OK. There was a mistake in my DATA...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use NOW() function of MYSQL as below instead of sysdate:

```
SELECT c.REGION,COUNT(*)COUNT FROM OAS_CONTRACT a
INNER JOIN OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES b ON
a.CONTRACT_ID=b.CONTRACT_ID
INNER JOIN OAS_CONTRACT_OFFICES_DETAIL c ON
b.T2_CODE = c.T2_CODE
WHERE (a.EXPIRY_DATE >= NOW())
GROUP BY c.REGION ORDER BY c.REGION
```

Try it in SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5f309/3)